# What is the correct usage of convertAndSend method?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I want to know what are the correct ways of using the method - "convertAndSend".I went through the method signatures in AmqpTemplate class. But the codes in GitHub or the codes I found are not meeting the method signature prototype.
For eg -

These were the ones found in codes -

```
template.convertAndSend("Hello, world!");
```

But the method signature is -

```
void convertAndSend(Object message) throws AmqpException
```

The argument is Object message, but the use case found is String message.

Another use case found -

```
amqpTemplate.convertAndSend("tp.routingkey.1", "Message # " + messagCount++);
```

Here both arguments are String. But the method signature close to this -
    void convertAndSend(String routingKey, Object message) throws AmqpException;

So even here, in the use case, String message is used instead of Object Message.

How will this work?? Are those use cases correct??
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object can be any type, including String. The conversion is performed by a MessageConverter. The default SimpleMessageConverter can handle byte[], String or java Serializable. There is also a json converter.

Read the documentation.

Comment: Thank you. It helped a  lot.